# Is it a must to pass a parameter to a set method? In this case setting the value is depending on another field in the same object

Tags: java, model, getter-setter

I know it's the common thing and maybe the best practice to pass a parameter to a set method, but in this case the new field I'm adding is depending on the value of another field in the same object, here is an example of code:

```
    abstract public class BaseContent {

    protected String sentiment;
    protected Double sentimentScore;


    public String getSentiment() {
        return sentiment;
    }
    
     /**
     * Set sentiment value depending on sentimentScore value:
     * If less than 0, set sentiment as negative.
     * If more than 0, set sentiment as positive.
     * If equals to 0, set sentiment as neutral.
     */
    public void setSentiment() {
        if (sentimentScore != null) {
            if (sentimentScore < 0) {
                sentiment = "negative";
            } else if (sentimentScore > 0) {
                sentiment = "positive";
            } else {
                sentiment = "neutral";
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought about creating only a getter method and have this functionality there, but that will force me to update the value of the new field in the same getter method, also I don't care about saving the new value in the database if that helps.

I might be having wrong thoughts so please give me your opinion on this!

Comment: The method should not be there because what happens if someone calls `getSentiment` before calling `setSentiment`!? Either put the logic in the getter or put it into the setter of `sentimentScore`.

Comment: If the value of a field depends on the value of some other field, I would suggest to either calculate the value on-the-fly in the getter or calculate the value when the value of the depending field is set.

Comment: I'd say no field `String sentiment`, just a gettre with the logic returning a String

Comment: @azro My main goal is to have sentiment value stored in it, so I need it to exist as the front-end will be using it, I'm trying to avoid setting the value in it's getter method, I don't think that's a good practice!

Comment: @luk2302 Would that be a bad practice to set a value inside the getter method?
Also what if the `sentimentScore` is coming from the database? in that case the setter method of it won't be called, so I won't get use of having that functionality inside the `sentimentScore` setter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, adding only a getter for the new field solved it, after getting the model from the database, the mapper looks for all the setters & getters of the model.

```
abstract public class BaseContent {

    protected Double sentimentScore;

    /**
     * Get sentiment value depending on sentimentScore value:
     * If less than 0, set sentiment as negative.
     * If higher than 0, set sentiment as positive.
     * If equals to 0, set sentiment as neutral.
     */
    public String getSentiment() {
        String sentiment = null;
        if (sentimentScore != null) {
            if (sentimentScore < 0) {
                sentiment = "negative";
            } else if (sentimentScore > 0) {
                sentiment = "positive";
            } else {
                sentiment = "neutral";
            }
        }
        return sentiment;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment to the answer you're replying to

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE The answers above were comments to the question, I couldn't mark any as an answer, unless I'm missing something then that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

If String `sentiment` field is transient, then it may be just removed and computed in the getter as suggested in the comments:

```java
public abstract class BaseContent {

    protected Double sentimentScore;

     /**
     * Return sentiment value depending on sentimentScore value
     * If less than 0, set sentiment as negative.
     * If more than 0, set sentiment as positive.
     * If equals to 0, set sentiment as neutral.
     */
    public String getSentiment() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(sentimentScore)
            .map(sc -> switch((int)Math.signum(sc)) {
                case -1 -> "negative";
                case  0 -> "neutral";
                case  1 -> "positive";
                default -> "unknown";
            })
            .orElse("unknown");
    }
    
    public void setSentiment(Double score) {
        this.sentimentScore = score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the project I'm working on is written in Java 7, so I wouldn't be able to use lambda there. But using only a getter for that field actually solved it yes, so thanks again!